# Exim Autoreply router doesn't work for aliases

Tags: exim

I am using an autoreply router, based on a common recipe floating on the net:

Router:

```
uservacation:
  driver = redirect
  allow_filter
  domains = domain.com
  hide_child_in_errmsg
  debug_print = "R: autoreply for $user"
  reply_transport = vacation_reply
  no_verify
  require_files = /home/share/autoreply.txt
  file = /home/share/autoreply.txt
  user = Debian-exim
  group = Debian-exim
  unseen
```

Transport:

```
vacation_reply:
  debug_print = "T: vacation reply for $local_part@domain"
  driver = autoreply
  file = /home/share/autoreply.txt
  file_expand
  from = $local_part@domain.com
  to = $sender_address
  subject = "Re: $h_subject"
  text = "Automatic reply\n\n"
```

Autoreply:

```
# Exim filter
if ($h_subject: does not contain "SPAM?" and personal) then
 mail
 expand file /home/share/autoreply.txt.txt
 to $reply_address
 from $local_part\@$domain
 subject "Autoreply...[Re: $h_subject:]"
endif
```

This works well for most users, however one user has an alias in /etc/aliases which is processed by a `system_aliases` router before the autoreply.

If the email is sent to the alias, then the autoreply doesn't trigger.  I cannot figure out why, as the router above doesn't seem to care whether the local_part matches a system username.

Any ideas?  (By the way, I realise I am doubling up some of the elements there as I have tried different approaches).

Comment: Data is incomplete. Exim behaviour depends on the routers order and you have to show all of them that precede autoreply router. Also, as for me, in case you have used dovecot as LDA, it is much better to use dovecot's sieve/managesieve for autoreply/vacation functionality.

Comment: @Kondybas Is there something else in the preceding routers I should be looking for?  Everything else in the routers is vanilla Debian if that is useful.

Comment: First, change `$user` to the `$local_part` in the router. Then move up autoreply router in the list, just after routers that sends messages to the outer space.